# DatabaseError: ambiguous column name on annotation filtering

Tags: django, sqlite, django-orm

I'm trying to filter an annotation query. And it's giving me `ambiguous column name date_created`:

```
    truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date_created')
    qs = Order.objects.extra({'month':truncate_date})
    report = qs.filter(is_active=True, listing__device=device) \
    .values('month').annotate(Avg('amount_total')).order_by('-month')[:5]
```

When I take out the `listing__device=device` part the filtering works fine. I'm using `Sqlite3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to specify the table name:

```
 truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'table_name.date_created')
```